# Add progressBar to view progress percentage to a process in c#

Tags: c#, process, progress-bar

This is code about my process:

```
StreamReader outputReader = null;
StreamReader errorReader = null;


       ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(......);
       processStartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

       //Execute the process
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
        bool processStarted = process.Start();

                     if (processStarted)
                        {
                        //Get the output stream
                        outputReader = process.StandardOutput;
                        errorReader = process.StandardError;


                        //Display the result
                        string displayText = "Output" + Environment.NewLine + "==============" + Environment.NewLine;
                        displayText += outputReader.ReadToEnd();
                        displayText += Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "==============" +
                                       Environment.NewLine;
                        displayText += errorReader.ReadToEnd();
                        // txtResult.Text = displayText;
                    }
```

I need add progressBar to my form to calculate progress percentage to this process, but I dont know how do.

Im using Visual Studio 2012, windows form.

Comment: [It's a hard problem](http://xkcd.com/612/).  Setting a progress bar in code is easy enough, knowing how far you've actually progressed is another matter entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the process `OutputDataReceived` event to capture progress.  (assuming the process is giving any sort of updates).  You could format an initial output to return the total number of increments, and then bump the progress for each output event or actually parse the output data to determine current progress.

In this example the output from the process will set the maximum, and each following step will bump it up.

e.g.

```
progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
// for every line written to stdOut, raise a progress event
int result = SpawnProcessSynchronous(fileName, args, out placeholder, false,
    (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        if (eventArgs.Data.StartsWith("TotalSteps=")
        {
          progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
          progressBar1.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(eventArgs.Data.Replace("TotalSteps=",""));
          progressBar1.Value = 0;
        }
        else
        {
          progressBar1.Increment(1);
        }
    });


public static int SpawnProcessSynchronous(string fileName, string args, out string stdOut, bool isVisible, DataReceivedEventHandler OutputDataReceivedDelegate)
{
    int returnValue = 0;
    var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    stdOut = "";
    processInfo.FileName = fileName;
    processInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) ?? "";
    log.Debug("Set working directory to: {0}", processInfo.WorkingDirectory);

    processInfo.WindowStyle = isVisible ? ProcessWindowStyle.Normal : ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    processInfo.Arguments = args;
    using (Process process = Process.Start(processInfo))
    {
        if (OutputDataReceivedDelegate != null)
        {
            process.OutputDataReceived += OutputDataReceivedDelegate;
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            stdOut = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
        // do not reverse order of synchronous read to end and WaitForExit or deadlock
        // Wait for the process to end.  
        process.WaitForExit();
        returnValue = process.ExitCode;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic Process does not have a built-in mechanism to provide progress notification.  You need to figure out some means for the process you are starting to inform of its progress.

If you control that process, you might have it write to Standard Out or Standard Error, and use the

```
outputReader = process.StandardOutput;
errorReader = process.StandardError;
```

you have defined to read that progress back into your program.  For example, the process could write to Standard Error

```
10
31
50
99
```

and your parent process, reading `errorReader`, could interpret those individual lines as % complete.

Once you have a means of getting the % complete of the child process, you can use a [ProgressBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.aspx) to show that progress.

Comment: it seem very hard for me. Can you write an example clear please?